# php array replace across the keys

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So i have an array containing information that I need to join on another table, for each  key I need to join it onto the form_lookup table then I need to replace the keys of the array with the data I retrieved from my DB. My question is what would be the fastest and best possible way to do this? I already have the form_information array

### attempt:

```
   $form_titles =array();       
    foreach (form_information[0] as $key => $value) {
     $this->db->select('NAME');
     $this->db->from('form_lookup');
     $this->db->where('CODE', $key );
    $query = $this->db->get();
    }

   $form_names  = $query->result_array();
   $form_titles[] = $campus_forms;
```

now i need to replace the keys from **form_information** with the keys from **form_titles** array.

```
$final_array = array_replace($form_information, $replacements);
```

### form_information## (initial array)

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [FIELD_1] => information
                [FIELD_2] => information
                [FIELD_3] => information
                [FIELD_4] => information
                [FIELD_5] => information
                ...
            )
```

### Table form_lookup

```
CODE_ID | NAME
--------------
FIELD_1 | Name
--------------
FIELD_2 | ID
-------------
FIELD_3 | Contact
--------------
FIELD_4 | Lookup
-------------
FIELD_5 | Campus
```

### (final array)

```
[0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => information
                    [ID] => information
                    [Contact] => information
                    [Lookup] => information
                    [Campus] => information
                    ...
                )
```

Comment: that part is not important I know how to write the queries i just abbreviated it. I need help in replacing the keys.

Comment: @PHPglue that's nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_combine(array_values($form_lookup), array_values($form_information));
```

Comment: Using `array_values()` is not necessary, as `array_combine()` already uses values from each array. `Creates an array by using the VALUES from the keys array as keys and the VALUES from the values array as the corresponding values.` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Answer (score 1):

If both arrays contain the same `CODE_ID`s and they are in the same order, then PHPs `array_combine()` might be useful.

> **array array_combine ( array $keys , array $values )**
>
> Creates an array by using the values from the keys array as keys and the values from the values array as the corresponding values.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Something like this:

```
$new_array = array_combine($lookup,$initial_array);
```

Here's a [working example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/45d-sb6).

Answer (score 1):

I would use **foreach()** and **array_combine()**.

```
// Source data simulation..
$one_item = array(
  "FIELD_1" => "information1",
  "FIELD_2" => "information2",
  "FIELD_3" => "information3",
  "FIELD_4" => "information4",
  "FIELD_5" => "information5"
);

$form_information[] = $one_item;
$form_information[] = $one_item;
$form_information[] = $one_item;
$form_information[] = $one_item;
$form_information[] = $one_item;

$keys = array(
  "FIELD_1" => "name",
  "FIELD_2" => "id",
  "FIELD_3" => "contact",
  "FIELD_4" => "lookup",
  "FIELD_5" => "campus"
);

// The important part.
foreach ($form_information as $array){
  $result[] = array_combine($keys, $array);
}

echo nl2br(print_r ($result, true));
```

..prints out:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[name] => information1
[id] => information2
[contact] => information3
[lookup] => information4
[campus] => information5
)

[1] => Array
(
[name] => information1
[id] => information2
[contact] => information3
[lookup] => information4
[campus] => information5
)
```

... etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
foreach($form_titles as $i => $v){
  foreach($form_information as $q){
    $form_information[$i] = $q;
  }
}
```